# Javascript: append new key values to existing object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am adding to an array new objects but I'd like to instead have 1 Object with new key/values in it.

```
var mergeRecipient = function(){
    var mergeData = [];

    $('input:checked').each(function() { //for each checked box fetch element name and value

      var key_ = $(this).attr('name');
      var val  = $(this).attr('name').val();
      
    mergeData.push({[key_]: val}); //push to array - ps. i dont want to create new objects but rather a single object with keys and values.

      });
```

New objects are being appended to array, I want to append the keys and values to a single object instead.

```
const dataObj = [{
  "jurisdiction": "SCPB - LON"
}, {
  "firstName": "David Dynamic"
}];
```

Intended structure

```
const dataObj = [{
  jurisdiction: "SCPB - LON",
  firstName   : "David Dynamic"
}];
```

Comment: So instead of pushing into an array, set a property on the object. Does it need to be an object in an array at all…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use an array then.

```js
var mergeRecipient = function() {
    var mergeData = {};

    $('input:checked').each(function() { //for each checked box fetch element name and value

      var key_ = $(this).attr('name');
      var val = $(this).attr('name').val();

      mergeData[key_] = val;
    });
    
    // if you have to use an array later on
    // you can create it with var arr = [mergeData]
```